# Highlighting active page from within controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've come across many forms of these questions, but none are specific enough for my situation.  I have a basic AngularJS app, where parts of the relevant html are:

```
<nav class="navbar" ng-controller="NavController as nav">
    <ul class="nav" ng-bind-html="pages"></ul>
</nav>
```

The controller is defined as:

```
app.controller('NavController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$route', '$location', function($scope, $sce, $route, $location) {


    pages = {
        'home' : '#/',
        'resume/cv' : '#/resume',
        'publications' : '#/publications',
        'contact' : '#/contact'
    };


    $scope.getClass = function(page) {
        // if ($route.current.activetab == page)
        //  return 'active' ;

        console.log(('/' + page) === $location.path());

        if (('/' + page) === $location.path())
            // return 'active';
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

    $scope.listPages = function() {
        ret = '' ;

        for (key in pages) {
            // ret += '<li><a href="' + pages[key] + '" ng-class="' + $scope.getClass(key) + '">' + key + '</a></li>' ;
            ret += '<li><a href="' + pages[key] + '" ng-class="{active:' + $scope.getClass(key) + '}">' + key + '</a></li>' ;
            // ret += '<li><a href="' + pages[key] + '" ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == ' + key + '">' + key + '</a></li>' ;
        }

        return ret
    };

    $scope.pages = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.listPages()) ;

}]);
```

Based on what's commented, you can see I've tried several flavors of the `ret` variable.  I can get an active class using `class=" + $scope.getClass(page)`, but this doesn't update when I click on other links.  I resorted to `ng-class`, but it doesn't seem to put the class in place.

I can provide additional code or output if necessary.

Comment: In addition, what are the best practices for including nav menus in Angular JS apps?  Should I just write the HTML in the included html file, or is it okay to proceed as I have done in the example above, where I inject html using `trustAsHtml`.  Apologies, I'm new to Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ngBindHtml` just use `ngRepeat` to render list:

```
<nav class="navbar" ng-controller="NavController as nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in pages">
            <a ng-href="{{value}}" ng-class="{active: getClass(key)}">{{key}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Where `pages` is a scope property:

```
$scope.pages = {
    'home' : '#/',
    'resume/cv' : '#/resume',
    'publications' : '#/publications',
    'contact' : '#/contact'
};
```

Comment: This worked great.  Totally forgot about `ng-repeat`.  Will mark answer as soon as SO lets me.